# Perl grouping data from two columns

Tags: perl, grouping, rows

I currently have a perl script which appends to a file with the content in this fashion:

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
a 2
b 3
c 4
a 3
b 4
c 5
```

and I want the output to be like this:

```
 a 1 2 3
 b 2 3 4
 c 3 4 5
```

This is my code which is extracting 2 columns from a file:

```
open my $file_in, "<", "input_file.txt" or die($!);
open my $file_out,   '>', 'output_file.txt' or die $!;

$now_string = localtime;
print "$now_string\n";
while( <$file_in> ) {
    next unless $i++;
    my @columns = split /\s+/, $_;
    print $file_out "$now_string\t$columns[0]\t$columns[2]\n";

}
close $file_in;
close $file_out or die $!;
```

Any ideas please? I'm using a Solaris 9 machine so can't run perl modules or similarly perl -E, perl -lane. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try something yourself and show us what you've tried and we can go from there.

Comment: first glance: `parse.pl` and `$ perl parse.pl input.txt`. You win!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
perl -le'
  push @{$h{$_->[0]}}, $_->[1] for map [split], <>;
  print join " ", $_, @{$h{$_}} for sort keys %h;
' file
```

`perl script.pl input_file.txt > output_file.txt`

```
$\ = "\n";
push @{$h{$_->[0]}}, $_->[1] for map [split], <>;
print join " ", $_, @{$h{$_}} for sort keys %h;
```

more lengthy (and approximate) version,

```
$\ = "\n"; # append newline when invoking print

my %h;
# read lines from STDIN
while (<>) {
  # split line on white spaces
  my @F = split;
  # push value of second column into $h{$F[0]} array
  push @{ $h{$F[0]} }, $F[1];
}

# sort unique values of first column
for my $k (sort keys %h) {

  # print value of first column, 
  # together with values belonging to it
  print join " ", $k, @{ $h{$k} };
}
```

Comment: I'm using a Solaris 9 machine so can't run perl modules or similarly perl -E, perl -lane

Comment: v5.6.1 built for sun4-solaris-64int

Comment: Yes of course but I got the error "v: Undefined variable."

Comment: Would you kindly explain what those 3 lines are exactly doing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want `partition_by` from `List::UtilsBy`?

```
use 5.010;
use List::UtilsBy 'partition_by';

my @pairs = (
  [ 'a', 1 ],
  [ 'b', 2 ],
  ...
);

my %groups = partition_by { $_->[0] } @pairs;

foreach my $group ( sort keys %groups ) {
  say "Group $group: " . join " ", @{$groups{$group}};
}
```

Comment: I'm using a Solaris 9 machine so can't run perl modules or similarly perl -E, perl -lane

Comment: Why does Solaris 9 not allow "perl modules"? If you can put your own code on there, you can install modules. Even in $HOME or alongside your application if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, but it helps to know how you got the data so far - variable?

You need a HashArray. Someting like that:

```
$x->{'a'} ||= []; # init array
push $x->{'a'}, 1; # add value
```

...

```
foreach my $h (keys %$x){
 print $h;
 foreach my $a (@{$h->{ $h }}){
  print $h->{ $h }; 
 }
 print "\n";
}
```

I did not run the code, just hacked it in here.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lane "
  push @{$v{shift @F}}, @F; 
  END { print qq{$_ @{$v{$_}}} for sort keys %v }
" file1.txt
```

Outputs:

```
a 1 2 3
b 2 3 4
c 3 4 5
```

Comment: I'm using a Solaris 9 machine so can't run perl modules or similarly perl -E, perl -lane

Answer (score 0):

You should put atleast what you have tried so far, not just the question. You can easily do it using hashes.

```
use Data::Dumper;
use autodie;

# Parse text file
open(FH,$ARGV[0]);
my @array=<FH>;
my %hash;

foreach(@array)
{
    $_=~m/(\w+)\s(\w+)/;
    push(@{$hash{$1}},$2);
}

print Dumper \%hash;
```

Comment: I'm using a Solaris 9 machine so can't run perl modules or similarly perl -E, perl -lane.